# access 2016 query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need some help with creating a query.  This is an inventory application where Product1 is moved from location A to location B and then to location C. Location B should then have zero inventory for Product1.  I have a table that stores all the movements as follows:

```
Movements (
    ProductName,
    QtyMoved,
    LocationFrom,
    LocationTo
)
```

Two entries might be:

```
ProductName | QtyMoved | LocationFrom | LocationTo
------------+----------+---------------------------
"Product1"  |      500 | "LocationA"  | "LocationB"
"Product1"  |      500 | "LocationB"  | "LocationC"
```

This query lists the above entries:

```
SELECT
    ProductName, QtyMoved, LocationFrom, LocationTo    
FROM
    Movements
WHERE
    LocationFrom = 'LocationB'
    OR
    LocationTo = 'locationB';
```

What I want is to calculate and list the total Qty in 'locationB' for 'Product1', (which would be zero, in this case).

I would like the datasheet view of the query to show 3 columns, `ProductName`, `QtyMoved` and `'LocationB'`. I believe what I need is an expression like:

```
(total qty of Product1 in locationFrom for locationB) minus (total qty of Product1 in locationTo for locationB).
```

Perhaps this would be easier if I was to create a report instead of a query.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something descriptive of the problem you're having or the question you're asking. If you remove the product name from the title, it leaves *query*, which has zero usefulness. Your title should be informative enough that it will have meaning to a future reader who sees it in a search result. (What you're looking for is called a *running total*, which should give you a good search phrase to use here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a UNION query to add the moves into a location and subtract the moves out of a location - sommething like

```
Select ProductName, LocationTo as Location, QtyMoved as Balance from Movements
Union All Select ProductName, LocationFrom, -QtyMoved from Movements
```

After you save this query, you can use it as the source for a 2nd query to get the balances, something like

```
Select ProductName, Location, Sum(Balance) as Balance from [Movements Summary]
```

Comment: Thank you Ken, I will try to be more specific in my description.  I was able to find some good information for future use searching 'running total'.

Comment: Thank you Don.  I'm relatively new to Access.  The use of UNION ALL did the trick.  I now also understand the need for 2 queries to make this happen.